# Need similar function strtotime("next monday") in Swift

Tags: swift

As the title, I want to get next monday (0 AM) I've read "Date and Time Programming Guide" but I don't figure out which function similar to strtotime("next monday") in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to calculate the NSDate of next monday, try this

```
let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

let startOfDayComponents = gregorianCalendar.components((.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond), fromDate: NSDate())
startOfDayComponents.hour = 0
startOfDayComponents.minute = 0
startOfDayComponents.second = 0
let todayAtStartOfDay = gregorianCalendar.dateFromComponents(startOfDayComponents)!

//Sunday == 1, Saturday == 7
let mondayIndex = 2
let todaysWeekday = gregorianCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: todayAtStartOfDay)
let daysUntilNextMonday = (mondayIndex + 7 - todaysWeekday) % 7

let dayAddComponent = NSDateComponents()
dayAddComponent.day = daysUntilNextMonday
let nextMonday = gregorianCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dayAddComponent, toDate: todayAtStartOfDay, options: nil)
```

If this isn't exactly what you are looking for, play around with this in a Playground. It is a pretty fantastic tool for a job like this.

Comment: I found that we can replace 
`let startOfDayComponents = gregorianCalendar.components((.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond), fromDate: NSDate())
startOfDayComponents.hour = 0
startOfDayComponents.minute = 0
startOfDayComponents.second = 0
let todayAtStartOfDay = gregorianCalendar.dateFromComponents(startOfDayComponents)!
`
with `let todayAtStartOfDay = NSDate().beginningOfDay()`

Comment: I can't find this method in the documentation. Do you have an extension on NSDate that implements this?

Comment: No problem. It's certainly clearer to break this big chunk of code up into smaller functional pieces like the extension. Also, you should accept the answer if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

You can try `NSDate.dateWithNaturalLanguageString()`, but it's deprecated in 10.10.

And here's the Apple comment about it: "This method supports only a limited set of colloquial phrases, primarily in English. It may give unexpected results, and its use is strongly discouraged. To create a date object from a string, you should use a date formatter object instead (see NSDateFormatter and Data Formatting Guide)."